# Need to read the DB2 DAS parameters

Tags: db2, db2-9.7, db2-9.5

I need to read the DB2 DAS Parameters via any method other than DB2 Command "get admin configuration".

I need to read the parameters like EXEC_EXP_TASK or SCHED_ENABLE from file or database.

I cannot find any reference of any files on DB2 where these parameters would be available or any table from where I can fetch these parameters via select query.

Any Pointers?

Comment: Could you write a stored procedure which called EXEC_EXP_TASK and populated a table with the current value yourself?  Then either call that sproc programmatically prior to reading the table or have it scheduled to update table periodically?

Comment: The DAS is a service outside of any database (you don't even have to install the DAS or have it running to have DB2 running). And in fact IBM deprecated the DAS in future versions of DB2 (10.1 and above I believe). So you may not be able to do what you were hoping. And even if you could it would be brittle.